# In python, how to print the docstrings of all functions defined in an imported module, without the functions that the imported module itself imported?

Tags: python, function, module, docstring

The following code prints each function's docstring from an imported module. However, the results incude some functions that were not defined within the module, but rather, were imported by the module.

```
import inspect
import my_module

all_functions = inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isfunction)

for i in all_functions:
    print i[0]           # print function name                                                      
    print i[1].__doc__   # print docstring
```

How can I print *only* the docstrings of functions defined within the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions have a `__module__` attribute storing the name of the module they were defined in. You can check if that matches the module you're inspecting. Note that this will frequently miss functions that actually are part of a module's API, but were defined in a different module. For example, `heapq.heappush.__module__ == '_heapq'`, because the function is actually defined in a C module `_heapq` and `import *`ed into the Python module `heapq`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Had to convert the function to a `str` on the if statement in order to do the check: `if str(i[1].__module__) == 'my_module':` (in reference to the example in the question)